# Slow query performance SQL 2016/SQL219 with new Cardinality Estimator

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2019, cardinality-estimation

We have some of our queries that are ten times slower than with the old CE ... there are a lot of sites explaining this "problem".

But here we have an example where all the time is passed is the "SQL Server parse and compile time" part ...

Plans are the same : 8% of index seek on table "T" and 92% of Clustered index update

```
UPDATE T
SET Value = 0.703645756
WHERE Col1 = '05/01/2022'
AND Col2 = '57XGOXYBT4OMXIFI'
AND Col3 = 372
AND Col4 = 'XX7R78OLRVJX9J2U'
AND Col5 <> 0.703645758
```

SQL 2008 :

**SQL Server parse and compile time:
CPU time = 78 ms, elapsed time = 83 ms.
Table 'T'. Scan count 1, logical reads 8, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.**
SQL Server parse and compile time:
CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.

(1 row affected)

Completion time: 2022-06-23T12:17:27.7728479+02:00

SQL 2016 :
**SQL Server parse and compile time:
CPU time = 1078 ms, elapsed time = 1108 ms.**
SQL Server parse and compile time:
CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 'T'. Scan count 1, logical reads 9, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
SQL Server parse and compile time:
CPU time = 153 ms, elapsed time = 153 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 157 ms,  elapsed time = 155 ms.

(1 row affected)

Completion time: 2022-06-23T12:18:47.7376589+02:00

All the solutions to come back to the old CE are working (compatibility level, force CE, query hing, ...) but do you have encountered same thing ?

Could Microsoft make something to this ?
Thanks

Comment: Is T a table or a view? If it is a view does it have WITH SCHEMABINDING?

Comment: High compile times are usually caused by some exceptionally complex code (even if it;s not in the actual query) such as partitioning or a large `IN` clause or a complex view. Please give a [mcve] containing your *actual* query and the table *and index* definitions.

Comment: Hi, it's a table, not a view ; we reproduce this even with small data

name rows =39535   reserved =34328 KB data = 10344Kb  index_size = 23632Kb  unused = 352 Kb

This table have one clustered index and 5 other indexes (2 filtered) and 6 triggers ... (2 for insert, 2 for update and 2 for delete)

Comment: Something very strange also is that the query was used in a loop for update record by record (and so now 780ms for each update) ... we change that to update all records in one time (+/- 5000) and it's the same time ... so we will do that for the moment